# Map names for generated relationship tables in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm giving Code first a try and I have the requirement of a prefix of (all) my tables in db.

In my DbContext I have these entities:

```
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

I can successfully map table names for my entities by overriding:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("w_people");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("w_departments");
    }
```

However for tables that created that don't directly map to a table I can't figure out to prefix.

In my example people can belong to many departments so a "non-entity" table is created by EF. *(I'm a EF noob so these tables probably have a fancy name)* So in my db I get three tables:

```
w_people
w_departments
PersonsDepartments
```

The PersonsDepartments table is what I'm after. How can I prefix these generated tables or change name/mapping after generation?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Departments)
               .WithMany(d => d.People)
               .Map(mc => mc.ToTable("w_peopledepartments"));
```